# Extracting variables chosen by glmnet or lars packages in r

Tags: r

I'm dealing with a large p small n problem (p>1000, n=150) and have decided to use glmnet and lars to select possible explanatory variables (as I understand *is* their functionality) rather than do this manually.

I have gotten out both a lars, and a glmnet object from the functions, but now can't discern how to extract from those objects, the names of the coefficients / the optimal model, that the functions have chosen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to determine the optimal model you'll need to estimate an optimal penalization parameter $\lambda$.  This can be done using the built in cross-validation function in `glmnet` called `cv.glmnet`.  Once you've fit your cross validated model with `cv.glmnet` the model object will contain all sorts of useful values.  These are described under the *Values* header in the `cv.glmnet` help file.  They can be extracted with the typical extractors, for example `coef()`, or using the `$` operator on the `cv.glmnet` object.

A word of warning though: be **very** careful with the default `glmnet` arguments.  Make sure you understand what **each one** is doing and why it's appropriate for your specific problem.

So almost verbatim from the cv.glmnet help file:

```
> ## simulate data
> set.seed(1010)
> n=1000;p=100
> nzc=trunc(p/10)
> x=matrix(rnorm(n*p),n,p)
> beta=rnorm(nzc)
> fx= x[,seq(nzc)] %*% beta
> eps=rnorm(n)*5
> y=drop(fx+eps)
> ## run cross-validation with all the default argumnets
> cvob1=cv.glmnet(x,y)
> ## one way to print the coefficients of the optimal model
> coef(cvob1)
101 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                     1
(Intercept) -0.1162737
V1          -0.2171531
V2           0.3237422
V3           .        
V4          -0.2190339
V5          -0.1856601
V6           0.2530652
V7           0.1874832
V8          -1.3574323
V9           1.0162046
V10          0.1558299
V11          .        
V12          .        
V13          .        
V14          .        
V15          .        
V16          .        
V17          .        
V18          .        
V19          .        
V20          .        
V21          .        
V22          .        
V23          .        
V24          .        
V25          .        
V26          .        
V27          .        
V28          .        
V29          .        
V30          .        
V31          .        
V32          .        
V33          .        
V34          .        
V35          .        
V36          .        
V37          .        
V38          .        
V39          .        
V40          .        
V41          .        
V42          .        
V43          .        
V44          .        
V45          .        
V46          .        
V47          .        
V48          .        
V49          .        
V50          .        
V51          .        
V52          .        
V53          .        
V54          .        
V55          .        
V56          .        
V57          .        
V58          .        
V59          .        
V60          .        
V61          .        
V62          .        
V63          .        
V64          .        
V65          .        
V66          .        
V67          .        
V68          .        
V69          .        
V70          .        
V71          .        
V72          .        
V73          .        
V74          .        
V75         -0.1420966
V76          .        
V77          .        
V78          .        
V79          .        
V80          .        
V81          .        
V82          .        
V83          .        
V84          .        
V85          .        
V86          .        
V87          .        
V88          .        
V89          .        
V90          .        
V91          .        
V92          .        
V93          .        
V94          .        
V95          .        
V96          .        
V97          .        
V98          .        
V99          .        
V100         .        
> ## a view of the cvob1 values
> str(cvob1)
List of 10
 $ lambda    : num [1:74] 1.78 1.62 1.48 1.35 1.23 ...
     $ cvm       : num [1:74] 31.3 30.8 30.3 29.8 29.3 ...
 $ cvsd      : num [1:74] 0.994 1.008 1.022 1.045 1.054 ...
     $ cvup      : num [1:74] 32.2 31.8 31.4 30.9 30.3 ...
 $ cvlo      : num [1:74] 30.3 29.8 29.3 28.8 28.2 ...
     $ nzero     : Named int [1:74] 0 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:74] "s0" "s1" "s2" "s3" ...
 $ name      : Named chr "Mean-Squared Error"
      ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mse"
     $ glmnet.fit:List of 12
  ..$ a0       : Named num [1:74] -0.157 -0.156 -0.155 -0.153 -0.149 ...
      .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:74] "s0" "s1" "s2" "s3" ...
      ..$ beta     :Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  .. .. ..@ i       : int [1:4266] 7 7 7 8 7 8 7 8 7 8 ...
  .. .. ..@ p       : int [1:75] 0 0 1 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 ...
  .. .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 100 74
  .. .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:100] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
      .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:74] "s0" "s1" "s2" "s3" ...
  .. .. ..@ x       : num [1:4266] -0.1565 -0.2991 -0.4299 0.0459 -0.5505 ...
  .. .. ..@ factors : list()
  ..$ df       : int [1:74] 0 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
      ..$ dim      : int [1:2] 100 74
  ..$ lambda   : num [1:74] 1.78 1.62 1.48 1.35 1.23 ...
      ..$ dev.ratio: num [1:74] 0 0.0172 0.0315 0.0475 0.0676 ...
  ..$ nulldev  : num 31247
      ..$ npasses  : int 298
  ..$ jerr     : int 0
      ..$ offset   : logi FALSE
  ..$ call     : language glmnet(x = x, y = y)
      ..$ nobs     : int 1000
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "elnet" "glmnet"
 $ lambda.min: num 0.23
     $ lambda.1se: num 0.402
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "cv.glmnet"
 > cvob1$lambda.min
 [1] 0.2300227
```

Comment: Any idea how to extract a glmnet model for a given $\lambda$ ?